# PHP extract "simple" array with foreach

Tags: php

I have this example:

```
$phrases = array('values[19]' => 'test2');

foreach ($phrases as $xkey => $values) {
echo "$xkey - $values";
// echos: values[19] - test2
}
```

How do I get the number "**19**" and "**values**" separated from `values[19]`?

Comment: `values[19]` is a string? i guess yes, `$phrases = Array ([values[19]] => test2)` is not valid code. This is debug

Comment: Invalid code - you should get several notices and warnings about use of undefined constants, unitialized string offset and so on.

Comment: Is values[19] supposed to be a variable like $values[19]? please check your code.

Comment: This code ended up too complicated, I just lost the need for "values". Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formatted string with [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php):

```
$xkey = 'values[19]';
list($name, $num) = sscanf($xkey, '%[^[][%d]');

echo "$name:$num";
```

`%[^[]` is a placeholder for all characters except `[`.
`%d` is a placeholder for an integer.

Answer (score -1):

use extract() function of php

```
$phrases = Array ([values[19]] => test2);

echo extract($phrases);
```

Comment: That is not gonna work - the code is completely illegal.

Answer (score -1):

Not the best way, but can fill your needs:

```
<?php
$phrases = Array ([values[19]] => test2);

foreach ($phrases as $xkey => $values) {
 preg_match_all('/[a-z]|[0-9]/', $xkey, $matches);
 $xkey = implode($xkey[0]);
 echo"$xkey - $values";
////echos values[19] - test2
}
```